# SQL Server Jobs vs Triggers for Data analysis

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am working on a transaction Table, where I am storing tasks as their status. Now I am working on a Dashboard Where I need to have the info of how many tasks are in which status.
I thought of having staging tables corresponding to each status so that it won't affect any transactional activity. Now to push data into the staging table I have two options.

1. Have a trigger on the transactional table on each status update i shall update the staging table.
2. Have SQL Job which will run every 5 minute to update the data in staging table

Please suggest which way to go..

Thanks

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f10fb4fe-0668-4f80-b804-c62b00ffe7e6/triggers-vs-jobs

Comment: Create an indexed view that SQL Server itself maintains automatically?